# Angular CDK horizontal scrolling with button

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

Working on a project where they have used the [CDK scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api) to enable horizontal scrolling which works perfect but because they dont want to use scrollbars there's an issue for desktop user als they can not scroll horizontal (the previous developer how has build this worked on a laptop).

I have looked at the documentations and on google but I cant find any solution to scroll by using buttons so is there a way to solve this?

Comment: hold shift and scroll :)? on the other hand, not using scrollbars on desktop is quite bad UX

Comment: I agree its bad UX (sadly its not my call)

Comment: so what is your question? horizontal scroll works on desktop, you just have to hold shift while doing so

Comment: my question is, how to use buttons to scroll. Yes I know (see previous comment)

Comment: @user759235 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-programatically-scroll-9tyqkg?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example.ts Check this out. Is this what you are talking about?